# Why don't the string characters change upon 'battle' function's execution?

Tags: c, string

The below code was written for "Weapon game(NOV19B-SC31)".
After many attempts, the problem I observed is that the "battle" function in the code is able to read but not change the individual characters in the strings.

From the below code, 
The 'res' value is not changing with respect to the conditions provided in the code. The initialized value, i.e- 0000000000, remains as it is throughout the code. This results in the answer to be 0 each time.

'''

```
#define Forn(i,N) for(i = 0;i<N;i++)

void battle(char *s1[11],char *s2[11])
{
int i;
Forn(i,10)
{
    if(s1[i]=='1' && s2[i]=='1'){
        s1[i]='0';
        s2[i]='0';
    }
    else if(s1[i]=='1' || s2[i]=='1'){
        s1[i]='0';
        s2[i]='1';
    }
    printf("%s %s\n",s1,s2);
}
}
int main(void) 
{
int t,count=0;
long long int n,i;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t>0)
{
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    char s[n][11],res[11]="0000000000";
    Forn(i,n)
        scanf("%s",s[i]);

    Forn(i,n)
        battle(s[i],res);

    Forn(i,11)
    {
        if(res[i]=='1')
            count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);
    t--;
}
return 0;
}
```

'''

Example Input:
1
3
1110001101
1010101011
0000000011

Example Output:
4

Explanation:
Example case 1: If the first person defeats the second person, weapons 1, 3, 7 and 10 are destroyed. Then, if the third person defeats the first person (who now has weapons 2, 5, 8 and 9), weapons 9 are destroyed and the winner has weapons 2, 5, 8 and 10, implies 4 weapons remain.

Comment: The question for the above code is available on [link](https://www.codechef.com/NOV19B/problems/SC31)

Comment: After few more attempts to alter the code, changing the function declaration from : void battle(char *s1[11],char *s2[11]) to void battle(char *s1,char *s2) gave the desired result. The former code appears to include both pointer and direct array application, then how did the compiler accept it? Also how was its execution defined?

Comment: Compiler didn't accept gracefully, it warned you many times. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking `array of pointer` as parameters to `battle` function

```
void battle(char *s1[11],char *s2[11])
```

But you need `array of characters`.

```
void battle(char s1[11],char s2[11])
```

---

If you had enabled the warnings,

```
warning.c: In function ‘battle’:
warning.c:10: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
warning.c:10: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
warning.c:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
warning.c:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
warning.c:14: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
warning.c:14: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
warning.c:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
warning.c:16: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
warning.c:18: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’
warning.c:18: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char **’
warning.c: In function ‘main’:
warning.c:34: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘battle’ from incompatible pointer type
warning.c:5: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
warning.c:34: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘battle’ from incompatible pointer type
warning.c:5: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
```